# Phonegap links in iframe open in app

Tags: jquery, cordova

I'm developing an app based on Phonegap and jQuery mobile.

In one page I have an embedded Youtube video which has a link to Youtube.
I have installed the inappbrowser plugin but when I click on the link to Youtube inside the video iframe it opens a fullscreen page and I have no way to go back to the app.

Is there a way to fix it?

I've already tried to hide the link to youtube but there is no way to do it.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: how are you using the inAppBrowser plugin?

Comment: I have installed the inappbrowser plugin. If I use window.open it opens a link in the browser correctly. Unfortunately I can't use window.open with links inside the iframe which is populated by Youtube.

Comment: then use javascript to prevent the link to work

Comment: I tried but it has no effect on the iframe cause the contents is from another domain :-(